# Display (and update) a dependent multi-select picklist

Tags: visualforce, multi-select

I have a multi-select picklist, which id dependent upon a nother picklist. The problem is rerendering chosen values using the basic apex:inputfield, this is a [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T2KyAAK).
I try to use a work-around and create a component myself but I can't get the picklistentries that are available to a given dependency. I tried using validFor but this is not available in Apex. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you perhaps post your controller code? Doing so might help provide ideas for part a the solution. My only initial thought is that picklists are essentially arrays of text strings. Perhaps working towards a solution based on that thought might help lead you to someplace productive.

Comment: @crmprogdev: thanks for your reply but since this error is a [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T2KyAAK) we decided not to work on it at this moment.

Comment: Understood.. Was a thought in case you were looking for a work around.